AWS Direct Connect vs AWS Snow Family
I was solving some practice questions for my SAA-CO3. I need some clarification with this question
A company needs to transfer 500 TB of data from its on-premises network-attached storage (NAS) system to the AWS Cloud. The data transfer must finish within a two week migration window. The data contains sensitive customer information and is required to be encrypted in transit to meet their security compliance standards. The company’s internet connection can support an upload speed of 100 Mbps.
Which solution meets these requirements MOST cost-effectively?
   
1)Use Amazon S3 multi-part upload functionality to transfer the files over HTTPS.
   

Create a VPN connection between the on-premises NAS system and the nearest AWS Region. Transfer the data over the VPN connection.

   

Use the AWS Snow Family console to order several AWS Snowball Edge Storage Optimized devices. Use the devices to transfer the data to Amazon S3.

   

Set up a 10 Gbps AWS Direct Connect connection between the company location and the nearest AWS Region. Transfer the data over a VPN connection into the Region to store the data in Amazon S3.

I selected the option 4 but the correct answer according to the test is option 3. Can anyone help explain why this is so?
***Correct answer
Use the AWS Snow Family console to order several AWS Snowball Edge Storage Optimized devices. Use the devices to transfer the data to Amazon S3.
Feedback
Although Direct Connect can support up to 10 Gbps, there are limitations on the IPSEC protocol and VPN connection to support the encrypted data in transit.
This would result in a best case bandwith of 1.25 Gbps, even with the 10 Gbps Direct Connect link.***

What is your question? Did you see [ask] already?

The most cost-effective solution for transferring 500 TB of data to AWS within two weeks, while meeting security compliance, is to use AWS Snowball Edge devices. These devices are designed for large-scale data transfers, offer built-in encryption for security, and bypass the limitations of slow internet connections. Compared to setting up a high-speed AWS Direct Connect connection, using Snowball Edge devices involves lower costs and is more efficient for offline data transfer.
